# VBA VLOOKUP Trouble Shooting Expected: End of Statement

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm writing doing my first macro with the intent of filtering a column to show only last month's entries via VLOOKUP. However, when I go to replace the integer month as function to find last month's integer from today's date, I get the error Ecpected: end of statement.

I did an initial VLOOKUP Macro as such.

```
Sheets("Opportunity Created Month").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
**"=7*",** Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="=*2018*"**
```

I then tried to replace the "=7*" with a function that would take today's date and show that integer -1 as below.

```
Sheets("Opportunity Created Month").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
    **"=TEXT(TODAY( ),"M")-1)*"**, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="=*2018*"
```

This is when I get the error about the expected end of statement.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Thank you
-James

Comment: I'm guessing that these are not real dates but some kind of string that is made to look like a date.

Answer (score -1):

You have un-escaped " in your string (should be doubled-up):

```
Sheets("Opportunity Created Month").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, _
     Criteria1:= "=TEXT(TODAY( ),""M"")-1)*", Operator:=xlAnd, _
     Criteria2:="=*2018*"
```

I don't know if `Criteria1` accepts a formula though...

Maybe try this instead:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, _
   Criteria1:= "=" & (Format(Date,"m")-1) & "*", Operator:=xlAnd, _ 
   Criteria2:="=*2018*"
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank's for going above and beyond. It totally fixed my issue!